# Flagging continuous observations and creating enrolment spans

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, lubridate

I have a few large enrolment datasets and I'm trying to create two things:

1. I'd like to flag each uninterrupted monthly observation (`final_df1`)
2. I'd like to create a dataset of uninterrupted spans (`final_df2`)

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
df<-tibble(id=c(rep("X",10),rep("Y",20)),
           date=c(ymd("20120101")%m+%months(c(1:5,7:11)),ymd("20120401")%m+%months(c(1:10,12:17,19:22))))

final_df1 <- df %>% mutate(cont_enroll=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,5),rep(1,10),rep(0,10)))

final_df2 <- tibble(id=c(rep("X",2),rep("Y",3)),
                  span_start=c(ymd("20120101")%m+%months(1),
                               ymd("20120101")%m+%months(7),
                               ymd("20120401")%m+%months(1),
                               ymd("20120101")%m+%months(12),
                               ymd("20120101")%m+%months(19)),
                  span_end=c(ymd("20120101")%m+%months(5),
                             ymd("20120101")%m+%months(11),
                             ymd("20120101")%m+%months(10),
                             ymd("20120101")%m+%months(17),
                             ymd("20120101")%m+%months(22))
                  )
```

I feel like there must be a simple way to do this between {lubridate} and {data.table} but I'm drawing up blanks. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'id', create an `interval` with the previous value of 'date' (`lag`) and the current 'date', divide by the `months`, check if it is less than 2, and take the cumulative minimum (`cummin`).  After creating the 'find_df_new', then we group by 'id' and the run-length-id of 'cont_enroll' column, and `summarise` with the `first` and `last` value of 'date' to create the 'span_start' and 'span_end' respectively

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
final_df_new <- df %>%
   group_by(id)  %>%
   mutate(cont_enroll2 = cummin(interval(lag(date, default = first(date)), 
       date) /months(1) < 2))  %>%
   ungroup
final_df_new %>% 
  group_by(id, grp = rleid(cont_enroll2))  %>%
  summarise(span_start = first(date), span_end = last(date), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: This is great, didn't know about cummin(). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this nicely with the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package. Your dates seem to really represent 1 month intervals, and the ivs package is dedicated to working with data of this type.

We can compute `final_df2` with `iv_groups()`, which returns the non-overlapping intervals that remain after merging all overlapping intervals.

Then the first row of `final_df2` per group represents the first continuous interval, so you just need to check if each range is within that interval or not to decide if it is part of the uninterrupted set to get `final_df1`.

Note that my `final_df2` looks different from yours, is it possible that you have an error in how you coded it?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ivs)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(
    rep("X", 10), 
    rep("Y", 20)
  ),
  date = c(
    ymd("20120101") %m+% months(c(1:5,7:11)), 
    ymd("20120401") %m+% months(c(1:10,12:17,19:22))
  )
)
df
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    id    date      
#>    <chr> <date>    
#>  1 X     2012-02-01
#>  2 X     2012-03-01
#>  3 X     2012-04-01
#>  4 X     2012-05-01
#>  5 X     2012-06-01
#>  6 X     2012-08-01
#>  7 X     2012-09-01
#>  8 X     2012-10-01
#>  9 X     2012-11-01
#> 10 X     2012-12-01
#> # … with 20 more rows

df <- df %>%
  mutate(start = date, end = date + months(1), .keep = "unused") %>%
  mutate(range = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused")

df
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    id                       range
#>    <chr>               <iv<date>>
#>  1 X     [2012-02-01, 2012-03-01)
#>  2 X     [2012-03-01, 2012-04-01)
#>  3 X     [2012-04-01, 2012-05-01)
#>  4 X     [2012-05-01, 2012-06-01)
#>  5 X     [2012-06-01, 2012-07-01)
#>  6 X     [2012-08-01, 2012-09-01)
#>  7 X     [2012-09-01, 2012-10-01)
#>  8 X     [2012-10-01, 2012-11-01)
#>  9 X     [2012-11-01, 2012-12-01)
#> 10 X     [2012-12-01, 2013-01-01)
#> # … with 20 more rows

# `iv_groups()` returns the groups that remain after merging all overlapping ranges.
# It gives you `final_df2`.
continuous <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(range = iv_groups(range), .groups = "drop")

continuous
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   id                       range
#>   <chr>               <iv<date>>
#> 1 X     [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01)
#> 2 X     [2012-08-01, 2013-01-01)
#> 3 Y     [2012-05-01, 2013-03-01)
#> 4 Y     [2013-04-01, 2013-10-01)
#> 5 Y     [2013-11-01, 2014-03-01)

# The first continuous range per id
first_continuous <- continuous %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(range_continuous = range)

first_continuous
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   id            range_continuous
#>   <chr>               <iv<date>>
#> 1 X     [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01)
#> 2 Y     [2012-05-01, 2013-03-01)

# Join the first continuous range df back onto the original df and see if
# the current `range` falls within the first continuous range or not.
# This gives you `final_df1`.
left_join(df, first_continuous, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(continuous = iv_pairwise_overlaps(range, range_continuous, type = "within"))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    id                       range         range_continuous continuous
#>    <chr>               <iv<date>>               <iv<date>> <lgl>     
#>  1 X     [2012-02-01, 2012-03-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) TRUE      
#>  2 X     [2012-03-01, 2012-04-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) TRUE      
#>  3 X     [2012-04-01, 2012-05-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) TRUE      
#>  4 X     [2012-05-01, 2012-06-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) TRUE      
#>  5 X     [2012-06-01, 2012-07-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) TRUE      
#>  6 X     [2012-08-01, 2012-09-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) FALSE     
#>  7 X     [2012-09-01, 2012-10-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) FALSE     
#>  8 X     [2012-10-01, 2012-11-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) FALSE     
#>  9 X     [2012-11-01, 2012-12-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) FALSE     
#> 10 X     [2012-12-01, 2013-01-01) [2012-02-01, 2012-07-01) FALSE     
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>